# How can I fix my bash script to find a random word from a dictionary?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm studying bash scripting and I'm stuck fixing an exercise of this site: https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php#activities

The task is to write a bash script to output a random word from a dictionary whose length is equal to the number supplied as the first command line argument.

My idea was to create a sub-dictionary, assign each word a number line, select a random number from those lines and filter the output, which worked for a similar simpler script, but not for this.

This is the code I used:

```
  6 DIC='/usr/share/dict/words'
  7 SUBDIC=$( egrep '^.{'$1'}$' $DIC )
  8 
  9 MAX=$( $SUBDIC | wc -l )
 10 RANDRANGE=$((1 + RANDOM % $MAX))
 11 
 12 RWORD=$(nl "$SUBDIC" | grep "\b$RANDRANGE\b" | awk '{print $2}')
 13 
 14 echo "Random generated word from $DIC which is $1 characters long:" 
 15 echo $RWORD
```

and this is the error I get using as input "21":

```
bash script.sh 21
script.sh: line 9: counterintelligence's: command not found
script.sh: line 10: 1 + RANDOM % 0: division by 0 (error token is "0")
nl: 'counterintelligence'\''s'$'\n''electroencephalograms'$'\n''electroencephalograph': No such file or directory
Random generated word from /usr/share/dict/words which is 21 characters long:
```

I tried in bash to split the code in smaller pieces obtaining no error (input=21):

```
egrep '^.{'21'}$' /usr/share/dict/words | wc -l
3
```

but once in the script line 9 and 10 give error.

Where do you think is the error?

Comment: in `$SUBDIC` you are storing the actual words (the output of the `egrep` command), but then you are trying to execute these words (`$( $SUBDIC) ...`

Comment: Consider `grep -E "^.{$1}$" /usr/share/dict/words |shuf -n1` if you have GNU (Linux) or else `grep -E "^.{$1}$" /usr/share/dict/words |sort -R |head -n1` if running BSD/Mac.

Answer (score 3):

### problems

1. `SUBDIC=$( egrep '^.{'$1'}$' $DIC )` will store all words of the given length in the `SUBDIC` variable, so it's content is now something like `foo bar baz`.
2. `MAX=$( $SUBDIC | ... )` will try to run the command `foo bar baz` which is obviously bogus; it should be more like `MAX=$(echo $SUBDIC | ... )`
3. `MAX=$( ... | wc -l )` will count the *lines*; when using the above mentioned `echo $SUBDIC` you will have multiple words, but all in one line...
4. `RWORD=$(nl "$SUBDIC" | ...)` same problem as above: there's only one line (also note @armali's answer that `nl` requires a file or stdin)
5. `RWORD=$(... | grep "\b$RANDRANGE\b" | ...)` might match the dictionary entry `catch 22`
6. likely `RWORD=$(... | awk '{print $2}')` won't handle lines containing spaces

### a simple solution

doing a "random sort" over the all the possible words and taking the first line, should be sufficient:

```
  egrep "^.{$1}$" "${DIC}"  | sort -R | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

- `MAX=$( $SUBDIC | wc -l )` - A pipe is used for connecting a command's output, while `$SUBDIC` isn't a command; an appropriate syntax is `MAX=$( <<<$SUBDIC wc -l )`.
- `nl "$SUBDIC"` - The argument to `nl` has to be a filename, which `"$SUBDIC"` isn't; an appropriate syntax is `nl <<<"$SUBDIC"`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the script preserving its structure.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it. My test dictionary of words is in file `file`. It's a good idea to get all words of a given length first but put them in an array not in var. And then get a random index and echo it.

```
dic=( $(sed -n "/^.\{$1\}$/p" file) )
ind=$((0 + RANDOM % ${#dic[@]}))
echo ${dic[$ind]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing this activity and I create one simple solution.

I create the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk "NR==$1 {print}" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Here if you want a random string then you have to run the script as per the below command from the terminal.

```
./script.sh $RANDOM
```

If you want the print any specific number string then you can run as per the below command from the terminal.

```
./script.sh 465
```

[image: Here is output for the same]

Answer (score -1):

`cat /usr/share/dict/american-english | head -n $RANDOM | tail -n 1`

`$RANDOM` - Returns a different random number each time is it referred to.
this simple line outputs random word from the mentioned dictionary.

Otherwise as umläute mentined you can do:

`cat /usr/share/dict/american-english | sort -R | head -1`