# Create a script to find a random word from a dictionary

Tags: linux

The task is to write a bash script to output a random word from a dictionary whose length is equal to the number supplied as the first command line argument.

I tried to use awk command but it wasn't help full. I am not able to pass argument in that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Related [How can I fix my bash script to find a random word from a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60210875/3422102)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also doing this activity and I create one simple solution.

I create the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk "NR==$1 {print}" /usr/share/dict/words
```

Here if you want a random string then you have to run the script as per the below command from the terminal.

```
./test.sh $RANDOM
```

If you want the print any specific number string then you can run as per the below command from the terminal.

```
./test.sh 123
```